# Karhunen Loeve Procedure

Tags: matlab, matrix, linear-algebra

I'm trying to apply the Karhunen Loeve procedure to a translation-invariant data set. I understand the KL procedure, and how to create a mask to smooth out missing data. However, I'm having a hard time creating a program to model my Translation invariant data set.

The data set that I need to plot in matlab is:
[Translation-Invariant Data Set](https://i.stack.imgur.com/34Tlf.png)

And here's the matlab code that I tried to use to model it:

```
function [fmu] = kLProcedure(N, P, M)
for k = 1:N;
   for m = 1:M;
   for n = 1:P;
        x(m) = ((m-1)*2.*(pi))/M;
        t(n) = ((n - 1)*2.*(pi))/P;
        k = 1:3;
        fmu(x(m),t(n)) = (1/N).*symsum((1/k).*sin(k(x(m)-t(n))),k);
    end
end
```

end
With N=3, P=64, M=64;

I'm trying to use a nested for-loop to calculate each iteration of m, n, and t. and keep getting the error:

```
Error using  / 
Matrix dimensions must agree.

Error in kLProcedure (line 28)
            fmu(x(m),t(n)) = (1/N).*symsum((1/k).*sin(k(x(m)-t(n))),k);
```

And advice would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Could you share your data?

Comment: The multi variable function is the data in this instance. After we model the function successfully we use a use a randomized binary mask to to create approximations of the data at each point.

Comment: If the data is discrete the KL Base can be simply computed by the SVD.

Answer (score 0):

Honestly, I don't have an in-depth knowledge of the algorithms you are using, but looking at the formulation of the one you are trying to reproduce, I think the following code is what you are looking for:

```
fmu = kLProcedure(3,64,64);
plot(fmu);

function [fmu] = kLProcedure(N,M,P)

    k = 1:N;
    ki = 1 ./ k;

    Ni = 1 / N;

    m = 1:M;
    x = ((m - 1) .* 2 .* pi()) ./ M;

    n = 1:P;
    t = ((n - 1) .* 2 .* pi()) ./ P;

    fmu = zeros(M,P);

    for i = m
        for j = n
            fmu(i,j) = Ni .* sum(ki .* sin(ki .* (x(i) - t(j))));
        end
    end

end
```

Output:

[image: Output]

Comment: Thank you! That's what I was trying to do. For reference, I'll use this function in a procedure for smoothing out data with gaps in it. The assignment is based on the following paper. http://www.sdss.jhu.edu/~szalay/class/2017/everson-shirovich-josaa-12-8-1657.pdf

Comment: Thanks for sharing your knowledge! If my answer solved your issue, please consider marking it as accepted.

Comment: The structure works, thank you! But I did just need to make a small mathematical correction. In order to get the k-th term to work as a sequence for the function from k = 1:3, I took out the top line and included it in a for loop for a summation.

Comment: But thank you, I wouldn't have been able to get the structure / plot of the code to work without your guidance.

Answer (score 0):

[Translational-Invariant Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BpZzK.jpg)

```
function [fmu] = kLProcedure(N,M,P)

m = 1:M;
x = ((m - 1) .* 2 .* pi()) ./ M;

n = 1:P;
t = ((n - 1) .* 2 .* pi()) ./ P;

fmu = zeros(M,P);

  for i = m
    for j = n
        fmu(i,j) = 0;
        for k = 1:3
        fmu(i,j) = fmu(i,j) + (1/3).*sum((1/k).*(sin((k) .* (x(i) - t(j)))));
        end
    end
 end
```